# Find 3 eigenvectors and rife vectors of rank 1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve this without have to factor a polynomial of degree three of higher.

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 4 & 2 \\
        4 & 2 & 4 \\
        2 & 4 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Since the matrix has a null space of 2, both of the eigenvectors correspond to eigenvalue 0. Since the trace is 6, that means the third eigenvalue is 6. Thus we need to find the null space of:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -4 & 4 & 2 \\
        4 & -4 & 4 \\
        2 & 4 & –4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

This matrix only has the zero vector as null space

Where in my reasoning did I go wrong?

Comment: The dimension of the kernel of that matrix is 1, so you have one null eigenvalue. Since the trace is 6 you can say that the sum of the remaining two eigenvalues is 6.

Comment: The matrix has, for sure, rank $\ge 2$, because $\det\begin{pmatrix}2&4\\4&2\end{pmatrix}=-12\neq 0$, so the null space has at most dimension $1$.

Comment: you have now problem of factoring here. Since you have null as an eigenvalue the charctaristic polynomial is of the form $x(ax^2+bx+c)$.

Comment: Why do you think this is a rank $1$ matrix?

Comment: You end up with the characteristic polynomial
$$
p(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 - 6x
$$
from which you can factor an $x$.